# Construction Specification Template

Tags: templates

I am trying to create a construction specification template in LaTex, specifically using Overleaf. I'm an engineer at a small specialty construction company. The engineering team has varying experience with LaTex and Construction Specifications, think MasterSpec. I've been trying to find a template for Latex to use to create MasterSpec type specifications. I've looked around a little bit, but I think the Civil/Structural Engineering communities have been slow to adopt, or even to investigate, LaTex. Has anyone ever run across a Construction Specification template? If not, I'm fully prepared to create my own, it's just that my LaTex skills are very beginning.

Edit: Added link to an example. The example is from the Utah Department of Transportation's standard construction specification.
[Example Specification](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zykCkTXs6RA89BhUdciMhkgeRSdSM6NQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: So you want to recreate something like [this](https://products-specpoint.mydeltek.com/product/5f9b877f-6a27-480f-8d0a-eaf74564e6c1_e7721e20-6869-4111-b717-5ed9ad131fca) (click on download button to view the document)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: most people here (including me) will have no idea about masterspec can you give an example of the kind of input you expect and a (faked) intended output.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The linked example looks not too hard to reproduce. I would suggest that you take a look at the `titlesec` and the `enumitem` packages, since you probably only really need to style headers for sections and enumerations.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and comments. They have helped immensely. I look forward to diving deeper into LaTex and using it more often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could get you started. You can place the preamble in a separate file and load it whenever you need it. Or you can make a .cls file out of it or a package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\AtBeginDocument{\raggedright}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=2cm, left=3cm, bottom=4.5cm}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\part}[hang]{\normalsize\bfseries}{{\makebox[2cm][l]{\MakeUppercase{Part} \arabic{part}}}}{0pt}{\MakeUppercase}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalsize\bfseries}{{\makebox[1cm][l]{\arabic{part}.\thesection}}}{0pt}{\MakeUppercase}
\titlespacing{\part}{0pt}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{para}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[para]{label=\Alph*., leftmargin=2cm, labelwidth=1cm, labelsep=0pt, align=left, nosep, topsep=1\baselineskip}
\setlist[para, 2]{label=\arabic*., leftmargin=!, topsep=0pt}         
\setlist[para, 3]{label=\alph*., leftmargin=!, topsep=0pt}
\setlist[para, 4]{label=\arabic*), leftmargin=!, topsep=0pt}
\setlist[para, 5]{label=\alph*), leftmargin=!, topsep=0pt}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{%
    \null\hfill\spectitle\hfill\null\newline
    \null\hfill\specnumber{} -- Page \thepage{} of \pageref{LastPage}\hfill\null\newline
    \null\hfill\specfooter\newline
    \null\hfill Latest Revision: \specrevision%
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand{\snumber}[1]{\def\specnumber{#1}}
\newcommand{\stitle}[1]{\def\spectitle{#1}}
\newcommand{\footer}[1]{\def\specfooter{#1}}
\newcommand{\revision}[1]{\def\specrevision{#1}}

\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
    \begingroup\centering%
    {\large\textbf{\MakeUppercase{Section \specnumber}}}\par\vspace{1\baselineskip}%
    {\Large\textbf{\MakeUppercase{\spectitle}}}\par\vspace{2\baselineskip}%
    \endgroup%
}

\newcommand{\sectionend}{%
    \bigskip%
    \begingroup\centering%
    \MakeUppercase{End of section}\par%
    \endgroup%
}

\newcommand{\notused}{%
    \vspace{-2\baselineskip}%
    \hfill\makebox[10cm][l]{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{not used}}}%
}

% ===== %

\snumber{00100}
\stitle{General Provisions}

\footer{2022 Standard Specifications}
\revision{February 18, 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\part{General}

\section{Section Includes}

\begin{para}
\item Provisions related to the interpretation of the contract. 
    \begin{para}
    \item Includes document organization, language, and communication.
    \end{para}
\end{para}

\section{Organization}

\begin{para}
\item Specifications 
    \begin{para}
    \item The specifications are organized by sections.
        \begin{para}
        \item The specifications are organized by sections.
            \begin{para}
            \item Each section defines a portion of the project requirements and is identified by a number and a title.
            \item References to specification sections use section numbers.
                \begin{para}
                \item Section references apply to the complete specification section consisting of the Standard Specification and Special Provision for the referenced section.
                \end{para}
            \end{para}
        \end{para}
    \end{para}
\end{para}

\section{Communication}

\begin{para}
\item Submit documents and direct questions in writing to the Engineer.
\item Orders, approvals, authorizations, and requests to the Contractor are by the Engineer unless specifically described as by another.
\item The following items from the Department are in writing:
    \begin{para}
    \item Approvals
    \item Authorizations
    \item Decisions
    \item Notifications
    \item Orders
    \item Responses
    \item Direction
    \end{para}
\end{para}

\part{Execution} \notused

\sectionend

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly!